# On the UCP(unified control plane) we are getting the popup that some services are missing

Tags: kubernetes, docker-swarm, docker-registry, docker-swarm-mode, docker-ucp

I am using the UCP for managing the docker swarm services.
But we are getting the popup on our UI
Warning: some services are missing their Swarm placement constraints. This may cause Swarm services to run unexpectedly on Kubernetes nodes. See https://www.docker.com/ for more information

Please help here to resolve the issue

In the UCP portal we are getting the constrint option we few constraint are already set.
we don't have idea how to set the new contraint again.also we are not sure what information to add there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.